# React php connecting with a different port

Tags: php, tcp, connection, reactphp

I have two files opening a new socket and want them to connect to each other using React PHP. The following two files are the sockets:

First file `test1.php`

```
<?php

include 'vendor/autoload.php';

$socket = new \React\Socket\SocketServer('127.0.0.1:3030');
$socket->on('connection', function(\React\Socket\ConnectionInterface $connection) {
    echo '[' . $connection->getRemoteAddress() . ' connected]' . PHP_EOL;
});
```

Second file `test2.php`

```
<?php

include 'vendor/autoload.php';

$socket = new \React\Socket\SocketServer('127.0.0.1:3031');
$connector = new \React\Socket\Connector();
$connector->connect('127.0.0.1:3030')
    ->then(function(\React\Socket\ConnectionInterface $connection) {
        echo '[Connected with ' . $connection->getRemoteAddress() . ']' . PHP_EOL;
    });
```

If I run `php test1.php` and then `php test2.php` I would expect the following outcome:

```
[Connected with tcp://127.0.0.1:3030]
[tcp://127.0.0.1:3031 connected]
```

However, the result is:

```
[Connected with tcp://127.0.0.1:3030]
[tcp://127.0.0.1:61594 connected]
```

What am I doing wrong here? How do I get React PHP to connect with the 3031 port?

Answer (score 0):

The `tcp://127.0.0.1:61594` is actually the address of the client socket here and `127.0.0.1:3031` the address of the server socket which is addressed by incoming connections.

When connecting to `127.0.0.1:3030` the `SocketServer('127.0.0.1:3031')` doesn't use it's server socket address as the client socket address, because this address is already in use. Instead your OS generates a random port number for the client socket (in this case `61594`).

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If our `test2.php` should act as a client, the `SocketServer` is not needed.

In order to bind a port to your client connection, do:

```
<?php

include 'vendor/autoload.php';

$connector = new \React\Socket\Connector(
    ['tcp' => ['bindto' => '127.0.0.1:12345']] // ip:port here
);


$connector->connect('127.0.0.1:3030')
    ->then(function(\React\Socket\ConnectionInterface $connection) {
        echo '[Connected with ' . $connection->getRemoteAddress() . ']' . PHP_EOL;
    });
```

This will use port `12345` for your client connection.
See also https://www.php.net/manual/context.socket.php.